# Invalid JSON in tag 'schema' when trying to save liquid file

Tags: json, shopify, schema, shopify-template

I am trying to add link to image in multicolumn on my website in shopify but this keeps coming up when I am creating a dynamic source and am trying to save it - Invalid JSON in tag 'schema'

I tried adding customisable text boxes and think i messed something up but dont know what, any help?

HERE IS WESBITE LINK https://68b27e.myshopify.com/?_ab=0&_fd=0&_sc=1

I tried adding customisable text boxes to my products and think i messed something up in my liquid themes but dont know what, any help? does anyone know how to save image link and also add customisable text boxes for product (IE if people want a name on product they can put it in text box)

Comment: Please read ["Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552) as well as [ask] and [edit] your post.

Comment: I think you need to share the code, which you tried and get error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find your section schema. Please use sample schema and then modify as per requirement.
https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/architecture/sections/section-schema